# Относительная фиксация положения камеры

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно реализовать жесткую фиксацию камеры относительно обЪекта (игрока) без наследования его поворотов?

```
public GameObject Player;
private Vector3 position;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    position = new Vector3(0f, 8f, 0f);

}

// Update is called late once per frame
void LateUpdate () {

    transform.position = Player.transform.position + position;
    //transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(-1f, -1f, 0f));

}
```

Так вот камера поворачивает свой вектор взгляда за игроком (не совсем понимаю почему, наследование?)

С разкоменченой строкой камера не поворачивается но мне кажется это костыль и скоординировать ее как надо у меня не вышло (наверное потому что костыль)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверил у себя - поворот не наследуется, сама камера приследует.
Единственный вариант, который мне приходит в голову - вытащите камеру из игрока. Она не должна быть чайлдом объекта игрока. Чайлды наследуют все изменения трансформации от своих родителей.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня камера была как раз чайлдом